# Text in images appears jagged/pixelated when getting texture from image URL

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the following code to get a texture from an image (.png) URL and set it on a `Raw Image` script:

```
UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(imageUrl);
yield return request.SendWebRequest();
...
imageObject.texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;
```

This works fine, but for images with text, the text looks very jagged. Below is an example comparison; top image is the texture loaded from the code above, bottom image is the same image but loaded as a normal asset in unity with `Texture Type` set to `Default`.

[image]

Is there anything I can do to improve the quality of the text in these images? I tried this, but it didn't seem to make a difference:

```
imageObject.texture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
imageObject.texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;
imageObject.texture.anisoLevel = 5;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you actually need to generate mipmaps for the texture in question. There are a [couple](https://forum.unity.com/threads/generate-mipmaps-at-runtime-for-a-texture-loaded-with-unitywebrequest.644842/) of [recommendations](https://answers.unity.com/questions/10292/how-do-i-generate-mipmaps-at-runtime.html) I found, but the TLDR is that mipmaps are only generated when you call [Apply](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html?_ga=2.45384685.838793419.1581627137-566425448.1558130724) and their availability is determined when you create a texture.

This leads to the following seemingly redundant recommendation:

```
UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(imageUrl);
yield return request.SendWebRequest();
var tempTexture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;

// create new texture, mipmaps enabled by default
var mipTexture = new Texture(tempTexture.width, tempTexture.height);

// copy the pixels over, this should all go into mip level 0
mipTexture.SetPixels(tempTexture.GetPixels());

// Unity should be smart enough to generate the rest.
mipTexture.Apply();
```

I hope this helps!

One more test: if you're unsure if the issue is related to mip mapping, the best way to check is to make sure Unity renders the UI pixel-perfect, set blending to FilterMode.Point, and present the texture without any scaling.

Comment: This works great so far! The only thing we noticed is that the images appear a tad blurry, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: So I've never tried this (I have no idea if it would work in Unity's pipeline), but you could try applying Unity's compression to the image and downloading that (ie: on iOS, upload a PVR or PVRTC file rather than a PNG). That might look closer to what you see in editor.

That becomes difficult on Android though (you may need ETC, ASTC, and DXT all available for different phones, or just fall back to PNG).